# I want to disable the website's ability to check for focus

Tags: javascript, onfocus

The link to the code - https://live.allenbpms.in/vc/impAppVendorVcBundle-ba46108f37.min.js
It is quite long but but i think this is the on

```js
function $e() {
  window.onfocus = function() {
    e.vcNamespace.chatAttendeesCount < 100 && (Logger.info("---------------onfocus"),
      l.sendMessage(angular.toJson({
        msgtype: "chat",
        subtype: "user-focus",
        userid: e.vcNamespace.user.userId,
        chatId: e.vcNamespace.user.chatId,
        focus: !0,
        time: Date.now() / 1e3,
        exampleid: e.unitInfo.exampleId
      })))
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what functionality you want to disable. The code snippet does not explain it on its own and why return true?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? If you don't want an onfocus eventhandler, why not just remove it? Or is this not your site? Then you would need to inject a script ...

Comment: @derpirscher Im trying to inject a script on another site. Basically whenever i change tabs the tab unloads so i have to load it again.

Comment: You can just override `window.onfocus = undefined` in the developer console. But that of course only lasts while you don't close the tab. If you want to automatically inject some script, you will need a browser plugin ...